# php alternative function for isset() to not return false if value is null

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any chanse to write alternative function for `isset()` function which will return true if key exists but its value is null

i know that there is php's [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) for that but i was thinking to if it possible to somehow check it by arrays key reffarance somehow or someting like that

```
// check if array key set
function issetAK($param){
  // some refarance check ?
}

$array = array('some_key'=>null);
issetAK( $array['some_key'] );
```

Douse any one experienced same or know solution for this ? or any idias ?

Comment: I don't understand why `array_key_exists()` is not appropriate for you. Perhaps you should add an example or something :-?

Comment: `array_key_exists` is exactly what you're looking for, even if it may not be your preferred syntax.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález actually it is appropriate i just wondered if it possible to do in way which i described with single param, to have some short function `issetAK($arr['index'])` instead `array_key_exists('index', $arr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly hard-code the array into a global variable but that'd be unmaintainable. The other alternative would be a class:

```
<?php

class ArrayHelper {
    private $array;

    public function __construct(array $array) {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    public function issetAK($param) {
        return array_key_exists($param, $this->array);
    }
}

$settings = new ArrayHelper(['width' => 200, 'height' => 125, 'ratio' => null]);
var_dump(
    $settings->issetAK('width'),
    $settings->issetAK('ratio'),
    $settings->issetAK('foobar')
);
```

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Whether this is an enhancement over plain `array_key_exists($param, $array)` is another story. It probably depends on the specific use case and overall app design.

Comment: Thank you, at least some solution :), but it is for sure longer then just use `array_key_exists`

Comment: Rename `$settings` to `$cfg` and `issetAK` to `has` and you'll save a few characters ;-)

Comment: Uhm, just alias `array_key_exists` if that's your main concern…?! :-P

Answer (score 1):

If an array key does not exist, precisely doing `$array['some_key']` will trigger a warning. `isset` is a language construct (more like an operator than a function) which gets around this limitation and does *not* trigger any errors, even if you do `isset($array['some_key'])`. There are only a handful of language constructs which can behave this way; off the top of my head those are `isset`, `empty` and `??`.

Any other use of `$array['some_key']` will trigger a warning and the expression will result in the value `null`, which exactly defeats the purpose. `array_key_exists` therefore takes two separate arguments: the array, and the name of the key you're looking for. Internally it's able to look up the existence of the key, and this way you can pass both necessary arguments into the function without triggering a warning in your PHP code by writing `$array['some_key']`.

Use `array_key_exists`, period.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation why my idea is wrong !